# HTML5 : What is the Regex pattern to allow only alpha bates , numbers and spaces for input text box in my angular 7 app?

Tags: html, regex, validation, angular7

I tried below patterns to allow only  alpha bates , numbers and spaces to my input text box in my HTML form, but it didn't worked out ..

1) ^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$

2) /^[a-z\d\s]+$/i

HTML code -->

```
 <input type="text" name="number{{ i }}" ngModel [(ngModel)]="container.number"
                                            class="input-control" maxLength="50" (ngModelChange)="numberChanged(container)" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_  ]*$">
```

In browser Developer tools (F12)-->

```
<input ngcontent-c23="" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-touched" maxlength="50" ngmodel="" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$" type="text" ng-reflect-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$" ng-reflect-name="number0" ng-reflect-model="@@##@eswd">
```

Can any one suggest correct pattern for my requirement ?

Comment: Try removing the `^` and `$` anchors, as they appear to not be necessary.  What is the current behavior of the `<input>` you mention above?

Comment: current behavior of my input box on form will accept container number and its going to be a array of inputs boxes based on container list. user can give number with mix of alpha bates and spaces.

Comment: Sorry, small correction  in my previous comment , i tried to tell you expectation. But actual behavior is allowing all characters

Comment: As mentioned above, try removing `^` and `$` from the pattern.

Comment: yeah i did it , but no luck

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are trying to mix HTML 5 stuff with Angular 7.